# Select 1st matching record from table one that has a match in table two

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm struggling to achieve what I trying to do, I need to select the 1st record from table 1 that has a match in table 2 and update table 2 with the value.

I have tried numerous ways and have looked at numerous post. But I either can only return 1 record or all records.

My previous attempts are below:

```
SELECT a.URL,
  a.Caption
FROM [EAN].[DBO].[tblHotelImageList] a
WHERE a.EANHotelID IN
  (SELECT b.EanHotelId FROM [EAN].[DBO].[tblEanFullTextSearch] b
  )
GROUP BY a.URL,
  a.Caption;
```

Above returns all records

```
SELECT a.Caption,
       a.URL
  FROM [EAN].[dbo].[tblHotelImageList] a
  LEFT JOIN [EAN].[dbo].[tblEanFullTextSearch] b
    ON b.EanHotelId = a.EANHotelID
   AND b.EanHotelId =
        ( SELECT TOP 1
                 a.EANHotelID
            FROM [EAN].[dbo].[tblHotelImageList]
           WHERE a.EANHotelID = b.EanHotelId
       )
;
```

Above returns all records

The above code at the moment is only trying to retrieve the records, I have not started on trying to update table with records

Comment: Hi DVT I'm only trying to do select a moment, will attempt update once I have overcome issue, I stated that in my question. No order, just after 1st records

Comment: So you just want the first record returned by your first query? How do you determine what is the first record?  Like Top 1  ORDER BY whatever determines first.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `left join`, use `outer apply`:

```
SELECT hil.Caption, hil.URL, . . .
FROM [EAN].[dbo].[tblHotelImageList] hil OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT TOP 1 efts.*
      FROM [EAN].[dbo].[tblEanFullTextSearch] efts
      WHERE efts.EanHotelId = hil.EANHotelID
      ORDER BY efts.??
     ) efts;
```

Usually, when you want one row, you want the row based on a particular order.  That is what the '??' is for.

You can use similar logic for an `UPDATE`.

Comment: Hi Gurwinder Singh, that does not work as tried earlier Guestroom
Restaurant
http://hotels/1000000/10000/100/1/1_13_b.jpg
211452
http://hotels/1000000/10000/100/1/1_14_b.jpg
211452 Notice ID's are the same 211452

Answer (score 0):

Since the mandatory record is in table 2 (tblEanFullTextSearch), make that the driver of your query. This query does what you asked for:

```
SELECT TOP 1
    a.Caption,
    a.URL
FROM [EAN].[dbo].[tblEanFullTextSearch] b
INNER JOIN [EAN].[dbo].[tblHotelImageList] a
    ON b.EanHotelId = a.EANHotelID
ORDER BY a.EANHotelID;
```

If you need the first match for all EanHotelId values, you can modify the query like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1
    a.Caption,
    a.URL
FROM [EAN].[dbo].[tblEanFullTextSearch] b
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Caption, 
        URL,
        EanHotelId,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order By EanHotelId) as RowID
        FROM [EAN].[dbo].[tblHotelImageList]
    ) a
    ON b.EanHotelId = a.EANHotelID
WHERE RowID = 1
ORDER BY a.EANHotelID;
```

There is probably another criteria for selecting the first match, but it is not in your question.

Comment: Hi Laughing Vergil, unfortunately both your examples return only 1 row

Comment: The second example is wrong if you want all cases. Remove the `Top 1` clause from the SELECT statement. My typo, my fault.